# Object mutations in graphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Here is my EventAttendee Object.

```
const EventAttendee = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'EventAttendee',
  fields: () => ({
    attendeeName: {type: GraphQLString},
    personalizedDateSelection: {type: new GraphQLInputObjectType()}
  })
});
```

The **personalizedDateSelection** property is an dynamic one and its properties are not known now. So, In this case, I have given **GraphQLInputObjectType()**.

But it gives an error stating **EventAttendee.personalizedDateSelection field type must be Output Type.**

How to define an ObjectType whose properties are not known ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted **personalizedDateSelection** property of **EventAttendee** to be of objectType but I dont know those properties in advance, but I am sure that it is of Object type.

So declaring this as GraphQLScalarType was the correct way to do it. Check out about [GraphQLScalarType](https://github.com/mugli/learning-graphql/blob/master/7.%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20GraphQL%20Type%20System.md#bonus-creating-custom-scalar-types). But we need to create a custom scalar type. All scalar types can be of input type. So here is my implementation:

```
const PersonalizedDateSelection = new GraphQLScalarType({
    name: 'PersonalizedDateSelection',
    serialize: value => {
      return value;
    },
    parseValue: value => {
      return value;
    },
    parseLiteral: ast => {
      console.log("coming in parseLiteral");
      console.log(ast);
      let value = {};
      if (ast.kind !== Kind.OBJECT) {
        throw new GraphQLError("Query error: Can only parse object but got a: " + ast.kind, [ast]);
      }
      ast.fields.forEach(field => {
        value[field.name.value] = parseJSONLiteral(field.value);
      });

      return value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to define an `InputObjectType` and not an `ObjectType` as stated.

With that said, what you can do is to declare `personalizedDateSelection` as a string for now, and then later adapt it as needed with a custom input object, once you know what it should contain. `GraphQLInputObjectType` is used to define **new** input object types, it isn't a type *per se*.